# Permanent bound for Laplacian matrix of signed graph

Tags: graph-theory, laplacian, permanent

In 1986, Prof. [RB Bapat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravindra_Bapat) shown that ([see here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379586901242/1-s2.0-0024379586901242-main.pdf?_tid=d8324bc0-3a39-11e7-b42f-00000aacb361&acdnat=1494940757_4b2659e88d484343897f8cf3ee1d9bce)) if $G$ is a simple connected graph on $n$ vertices, then, the permanent per$\big(L(G)\big)\ge 2(n-1)\kappa(G)$, where $L(G)$ is the Laplacian matrix of $G$ and $\kappa(G)$ is the number of spanning trees in $G$. The matrix $L(G)$ is defined as follows $$L(G)=D(G)-A(G),$$ where, $A(G)=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$, $(a_{ij}=a_{ji} \in \{0 ,1\}, a_{ii}=0 \forall i,j)$ is adjacency matrix of $G$ and $D(G)$ is a diagonal matrix whose $i$-th diagonal element $d_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}$ . It is to be noted that by the matrix-tree theorem ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem)) $\kappa(G)$ equals to any cofactor of the $L(G)$.

I want to find out similar lower bound for the permanent of Laplacian matrix of a signed graph. Let $G$ be a signed graph on $n$ vertices. Then the Laplacian matrix is given by $$L(G)=D(A)-A(G),$$ where, $A(G)=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$, $(a_{ij}=a_{ji} \in \{-1, 0 ,1\}, a_{ii}=0 \forall i,j)$ and $D(G)$ is a diagonal matrix whose $i$-th diagonal element $d_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|$ .

I noticed that the idea of using $\kappa(G)$ equals to any cofactor of the $L(G)$ does not work here. What could be the approach to find some lower bound for per$\big(L(G)\big).$